# Why does this org-babel c snippet produce no output?

Tags: c, emacs, literate-programming, org-babel

Basically, `printf` doesn't produce output if I put it in `main()`.

This works:

```
#+begin_src C
printf("Hello World!\n");
#+end_src
```

But this

```
#+begin_src C
void main() {
printf("Hello World!\n");
}
#+end_src
```

results in

> Code block produced no output

I have tried adding `:results output` to the `begin_src` line. I have tried including `stdio.h`. When I look in `*Messages*`, I see that when I wrap the `printf` in `main`, I get the error

> **Error reading results: (beginning-of-buffer)**

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cpp
#+name: main
#+begin_src C
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("Hello World!\n");

return 0;
}
#+end_src
```

Comment: That worked, even without the parameters being fed into main or the `#+name: main` (and I had to put a semi-colon after `return 0`). Apparently it just needed to be an int with a return?

Comment: It's always depends on used ANSI C standard.
If it's C89/90 you can write without int, if not int is necessary.

And yes you should add semicolon after return 0 it was mine mistake, thx.

Comment: Nope. As I play further, it doesn't matter what standard I use. Adding `:flags -std=c99` allows me to use c99 features, but doesn't allow me to get output from a void function.

Comment: void main() {...} isn't ANSI C standard, it's allowed by some C compilers but it's wrong. In ANSI C C89/C90 you can write just main() {...} cause int is implied.